# How to use "getElementsByClassName" to get multiple classes from same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have written some js to get an element by class name but the element I am targeting has two classes.

```
<div class="module gh">
```

This is the script that I am using to try and target this class.

```
var gh = document.getElementsByClassName("module gh");
```

For some reason I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '-webkit-animation' of undefined" Which is suggesting that the class cannot be found. What do I need to do here?

Here is the full code if anyone cares to help me clean it up and share why they would make changes I would GREATLY appreciate it. Just getting into JS btw...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('.carousel').each(function(index, element){jQuery(this)[index].slide = null;});jQuery('.carousel').carousel('cycle');});



var yPosition;

window.onload = function(){

yPosition = document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper").offsetTop;
}

window.onscroll = function(){

var stickyMenu = document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper");
var userOneSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user1");
var userTwoSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user2");
var userThreeSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user3");
var userFourSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user4");
var gh = document.getElementsByClassName("gh");

if( document.getElementById("sp-user1") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user2") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user3") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user4") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -100) ){ // compare original y position of element to y position of page

    userOneSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "0px"

    userTwoSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

    userThreeSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

    userFourSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

}

if( document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper") != null && yPosition <= window.pageYOffset ){ 

    stickyMenu.style.position = "fixed";
    stickyMenu.style.top = "0px";
    stickyMenu.style.boxShadow= "rgb(112, 173, 139) 5px 5px 1200px";
    stickyMenu.style.width= "100%";
    stickyMenu.style.zIndex= "1";

}     

else{          

    stickyMenu.style.position = "inherit";
    stickyMenu.style.top = "";    
}                       

if( document.getElementsByClassName("gh") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -400) ){

    gh.style["-webkit-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["-moz-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["-os-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["-ms-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style.display = "block";

}               
}
```

NOTE:The question was answered and here is my modified code for anyone who has the issue.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){//when document is ready - fire

var yPosition;//yPosition variable.

yPosition = document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper").offsetTop;// save original y position of element before scrolling.

window.onscroll = function(){// on scroll this will fire.

//declare all variables
var stickyMenu = document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper");
var userOneSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user1");
var userTwoSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user2");
var userThreeSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user3");
var userFourSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user4");
var gh = document.querySelectorAll(".module.gh");

    //below - if element exists and scrlling is at this point - fire
    if( document.getElementById("sp-user1") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user2") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user3") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user4") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -100) ){ // compare original y position of element to y position of page

        userOneSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";//user1 style
        userOneSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
        userOneSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
        userOneSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
        userOneSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
        userOneSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "0px"

        userTwoSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";//user2 style
        userTwoSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
        userTwoSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
        userTwoSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
        userTwoSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
        userTwoSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

        userThreeSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";//user3 style
        userThreeSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
        userThreeSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
        userThreeSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
        userThreeSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
        userThreeSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

        userFourSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";//user4 style
        userFourSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
        userFourSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
        userFourSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
        userFourSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
        userFourSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

    }

    //below - if element exists and scrolling is at this point - fire
    if( document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper") != null && yPosition <= window.pageYOffset ){

        //sticky menu style
        stickyMenu.style.position = "fixed";
        stickyMenu.style.top = "0px";
        stickyMenu.style.boxShadow= "rgb(112, 173, 139) 5px 5px 1200px";
        stickyMenu.style.width= "100%";
        stickyMenu.style.zIndex= "1";

    }

    else{

        //always show
        stickyMenu.style.position = "inherit";
        stickyMenu.style.top = "";
    }

    //below - if element exists and scrolling is at this point - fire
    if( document.querySelectorAll(".module.gh") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -400) ){

        //loop through array
        for(var g=0; g<gh.length; g++) {
            gh[g].style["-webkit-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";//class="module gh"
            gh[g].style["-moz-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
            gh[g].style["-os-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
            gh[g].style["-ms-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
            gh[g].style["animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
            gh[g].style.display = "block";

        }

    }

}

//fire carousel onload
jQuery('.carousel').each(function(index, element){

    jQuery(this)[index].slide = null;

});

jQuery('.carousel').carousel('cycle');

});
```

Comment: If `jQuery` in the code is [the jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), why to use native DOM queries?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @freshbm Please visit [My Site](https://ghostlyhaks.com)

Comment: Why do you looking for getting elements by multiple class names ?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns array like result, so  gh.style["-webkit-animation"] - should be like gh[0].style...

Comment: If your looking for one specific element, why use `getElementsByClassName`? That's what `getElementById` is for.

Comment: The top line of the code is something that automatically starts a carousel that I use every once in a while. It is not directly related to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Because the top element with an ID of sp-right applies to the whole site. I am only trying to target elements that have the class module gh this narrows down the animation to only the elements I want to be animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array result for:

```
var gh = document.getElementsByClassName("module gh");
```

because you have multiple divs with `class="module gh"`.

You should write something like this in your code:

```
for(var i=0; i<gh.length; i++) {
   gh[i].style ...
}
```

I have some example code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/j1tpkfa5/

or in your case:

```
if( document.getElementsByClassName("gh") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -400) ){
   for(var i=0; i<gh.length; i++) {
      gh[i].style["-webkit-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
      gh[i].style["-moz-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
      gh[i].style["-os-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
      gh[i].style["-ms-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
      gh[i].style["animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
      gh[i].style.display = "block";
   }    
}
```

Comment: Great I understand what you mean. I will give this a shot. This will go through each iteration of the array right?

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3C HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/dom.html#dom-getelementsbyclassname), your method should work. Moreover, remember that using `document.getElementsByClassName()` with an unknown classname return an empty array so it's never `null` (see your last `if`).

The comment of Teemu is true concerning [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) but given that you're new in JS, that's no big deal.

However, i see that your JS is executed as soon as possible when the web page is loading, so if your JS try to interfere with HTML elements that are not yet created, you get an error.

The first line of code that you see is executed when the DOM is ready, when all elements are created; the least that i could advice you is to put your `window.onscroll` inside the first depth of the JQuery code and the `window.onload` content before the window.onscroll in the JQuery.

I give you an advice:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  //You can create your yPosition variable here because it will be used only inside this function.

  //Then you can put the window.onload content here (only inside the function, since JQuery(document).ready() is doing the same thing as window.onload)

  // And here you can write your window.onscroll


  jQuery('.carousel').each(function(index, element){
    jQuery(this)[index].slide = null;
  });
  jQuery('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
});


var yPosition;

window.onload = function(){

yPosition = document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper").offsetTop;
}

window.onscroll = function(){

var stickyMenu = document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper");
var userOneSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user1");
var userTwoSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user2");
var userThreeSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user3");
var userFourSlideIn = document.getElementById("sp-user4");
var gh = document.getElementsByClassName("gh");

if( document.getElementById("sp-user1") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user2") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user3") != null && document.getElementById("sp-user4") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -100) ){ // compare original y position of element to y position of page

    userOneSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin1 1s ease forwards";
    userOneSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "0px"

    userTwoSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin2 1s ease forwards";
    userTwoSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

    userThreeSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin3 1s ease forwards";
    userThreeSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

    userFourSlideIn.style["-webkit-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["-moz-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["-os-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["-ms-animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style["animation"] = "flyin4 1s ease forwards";
    userFourSlideIn.style.marginLeft = "30px"

}

if( document.getElementById("sp-menu-wrapper") != null && yPosition <= window.pageYOffset ){ 

    stickyMenu.style.position = "fixed";
    stickyMenu.style.top = "0px";
    stickyMenu.style.boxShadow= "rgb(112, 173, 139) 5px 5px 1200px";
    stickyMenu.style.width= "100%";
    stickyMenu.style.zIndex= "1";

}     

else{          

    stickyMenu.style.position = "inherit";
    stickyMenu.style.top = "";    
}                       

if( document.getElementsByClassName("gh") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -400) ){

    gh.style["-webkit-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["-moz-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["-os-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["-ms-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style["animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
    gh.style.display = "block";

}               
}
```

Maybe I'm repeating myself but don't forget that `document.getElementsByClassName()` return an array of HTMLElement, not only an HTMLElement (mind the **s** after `Element` in `getElementsByClassName()`)

I hope that i helped you.

Comment: Very much I will take this into consideration and clean up the code. I do understand the "s" as I was trying to get all the elements but didn't know i needed to apply the CSS styles to each iteration in the array. Hopefully I am being clear.

Comment: OK, I have now redone the script and understand why you made your suggestions. The load is actually faster and is much smoother thanks so much for going the extra mile! I will post my working code in my question for all to see.

Answer (score 1):

use querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByClassName().

```
var gh = document.querySelectorAll(".module.gh");
```

This will return you the array of elements. You need to access it using index eg., gh[0] will give you first element. Check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/02wpodcc/).

check [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: That wouldn't work, `document.querySelectorAll(".module.gh")` would, I suppose

Comment: I tried both solutions using `document.querySelectorAll("module gh")` and `document.querySelectorAll(".module .gh")` Same error.

Comment: Unfortunately no it doesn't work. I also tried omitting the space between .module and .gh leaving your example above.

Comment: Can this happen because of how the page loads? I used `window.onload` to avoid this.

Comment: The above would work as explained if I was targeting just one or a few of the many elements with the classes called. However looping through all of them did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: The above will create an array that needs to be gone through by each iteration or by specifying which in the array to use. - Great help

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` uses CSS class names to identify elements in the document, meaning it will look into each element’s class attribute. An element can have one or more CSS classes, like in the case of our example document where we have a div with 2 classes `module` and `gh`. Using the getElementsByClassName selector you can select the item using either of the 2 CSS classes or even both.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('module gh');
console.log(el)
```

here is [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/etrvvacq/)

Comment: True, but in your example you only have one div with the class. I have many (which I should have mentioned I guess.) But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This code return an array of elements with specified classnames. The you need just to iterate through them. Anyway, it's looks that you gat the answer of your question

Answer (score 1):

Try and Modify this :

```
var gh = document.getElementsByClassName("module gh");

if( document.getElementsByClassName("gh") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -400) ){
 for(var k=0; k < gh.length; k++){

gh[k].style["-webkit-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
gh[k].style["-moz-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
gh[k].style["-os-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
gh[k].style["-ms-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
gh[k].style["animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
gh[k].style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would also work as its very similar if not the same as @freshmb. I will modify and test now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answer to this particular question was answered best by @freshbm and @Fraizan. They told me to use a for loop to go through each iteration of the array that was created by `document.querySelectorAll` this is what I did to modify the code.

```
if( document.querySelectorAll("module gh") != null && yPosition <= (window.pageYOffset + -400) ){ // compare original y position of element to y position of page 

  for(var g=0; g<gh.length; g++) {
  gh[g].style["-webkit-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
  gh[g].style["-moz-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
  gh[g].style["-os-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
  gh[g].style["-ms-animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
  gh[g].style["animation"] = "ffr 2s ease forwards";
  gh[g].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

This worked great to resolve my issue.